# loss NAN when use keras training ANN classification

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I have some data and wanting to classification.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2474 entries, 0 to 5961
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Age                             2474 non-null int64
Pre_Hospitalization_Disposal    2474 non-null object
Injury_to_hospital_time         2474 non-null float64
Discharge_results               2474 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 96.6+ KB
```

Age, Pre_Hospitalization_Disposal, Injury_to_hospital_time is feature data.

Discharge_results is wanting to predict.

I have check my data not null.

```
print(len(DataSet.index[(pd.isnull(DataSet['Age'])) | 
(pd.isnull(DataSet['Pre_Hospitalization_Disposal'])) | 
(pd.isnull(DataSet['Injury_to_hospital_time'])) | 
(pd.isnull(DataSet['Discharge_results']))]))
```

My code:

```
(train, test) = train_test_split(DataSet, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
trainY = train["Discharge_results"].astype('float')
testY = test["Discharge_results"].astype('float')

cs = MinMaxScaler()
trainContinuous = cs.fit_transform(train[['Age','Injury_to_hospital_time']])
testContinuous = cs.transform(test[['Age','Injury_to_hospital_time']])

zipBinarizer = LabelBinarizer().fit(DataSet["Pre_Hospitalization_Disposal"])
trainCategorical = zipBinarizer.transform(train["Pre_Hospitalization_Disposal"])
testCategorical = zipBinarizer.transform(test["Pre_Hospitalization_Disposal"])

trainX = np.hstack([trainCategorical, trainContinuous])
testX = np.hstack([testCategorical, testContinuous])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_dim=trainX.shape[1] ,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(8, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="softmax"))
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer='Adam')

history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(testX, testY),epochs=200, batch_size=32)
```

but I get `loss NAN` when training.

results:

```
Train on 1979 samples, validate on 495 samples
Epoch 1/10
1979/1979 [==============================] - 2s 1ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 2/10
1979/1979 [==============================] - 0s 165us/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 3/10
1979/1979 [==============================] - 0s 139us/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 4/10
1979/1979 [==============================] - 0s 137us/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 5/10
1979/1979 [==============================] - 0s 137us/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 6/10
1979/1979 [==============================] - 0s 141us/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 7/10
1979/1979 [==============================] - 0s 138us/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 8/10
1979/1979 [==============================] - 0s 141us/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 9/10
1979/1979 [==============================] - 0s 140us/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 10/10
1979/1979 [==============================] - 0s 144us/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
```

Does anyone can  help me? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looks like there is a mismatch between your labels and training loss. The loss `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` is for classification models with multiple categories. If you want to use this loss your labels should be integers (the index of the correct category) but I see in your code that your labels are floats:

```
trainY = train["Discharge_results"].astype('float')
```

Moreover, the last Dense layer of your model should have `n_classes` hidden units instead of just 1.

If your labels are really floats you are probably working on a regression problem and should use a different loss function (for example `mean_squared_error`).